# Flattening Code Creates Infinite Loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

I had a submit function that works however I’m trying to figure out why after I flatten the submit function and make smaller functions why I’m getting an infinite loop after the jquery ajax call when the submit function is called.

```
 public function form_is_valid()
 {
  /* Set validation rules for post data */
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|regex_match[/[a-z0-9]/]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|regex_match[/[a-z0-9]/]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('remember', 'Remember Me', 'trim|xss_clean|integer');

  /* Form validation passed */
  return $this->form_validation->run();
 }

 public function is_user_locked($user_data)
 {
  if ($user_data->lock_date !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
  {
   /* User is locked out */

   if (strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())) < strtotime($user_data->lock_date))
   {
    /* User is still locked out */
    return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
    /* User is no longer locked out */
    return FALSE;
   }

  }
 }

 public function check_user_status($user_data)
 {
  /* Match user status */
  switch ($user_data->user_status_id)
  {
  case 1:
   $this->output('Sorry you must verify your account before logging in!', 'Account Unverified', 'Error');
   break;
  case 3:
   $this->output('Your account has been suspended!', 'Account Suspended', 'Error');
   break;
  case 4:
   $this->output('Your account has been suspended!', 'Account Banned', 'Error');
   break;
  case 5:
   $this->output('Your account has been deleted!', 'Account Deleted', 'Error');
   break;
  default:
   return;
  }
 }

 public function output($message, $title, $status = 'Success')
 {
  switch ($status)
  {
  case 'Error':
   array('status' => 'Error');
   break;
  case 'Notice':
   array('status' => 'Notice');
   break;
  case 'Success':
   array('status' => 'Success');
   break;
  }
  echo json_encode($status, $title, $message);
 }

 public function start_user_session()
 {
  /* Start session with user id and clear previous failed login attempts */
  $this->session->set_userdata('uid', $user_data->user_id);
  $this->session->unset_userdata('failed_logins');
  $this->users_model->insert_session($user_data->user_id, gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
  return;
 }

 public function submit($post_username = NULL, $post_password = NULL)
 {
  if (!$this->form_is_valid())
  {
   echo 'test';
   die();
   $this->output('The form did not validate successfully!', 'Form Not Validated', 'Error');
  }

  /* Post values from login form */
  $post_username = $this->input->post('username');
  $post_password = $this->input->post('password');

  /* Test to see value of posted login form */
  //echo '<pre>';
  //var_dump($post_username);
  //var_dump($post_password);
  //echo '</pre>';
  //die();

  /* Get user data from post username value */
  $user_data = $this->users_model->get_by('username', $post_username);

  /* Test to see value of $user_data */
  //echo '<pre>';
  //var_dump($user_data);
  //echo '</pre>';
  //die();

  if (count($user_data) == 0)
  {
   /* User was not found in database */
   $this->output('The user was not found in the database!', 'User Not Found', 'Error');
  }

  /* User was found in database */

  if ($this->is_user_locked($user_data->lock_date))
  {
   /* User is locked from logging in from too many failed attempts */
   $this->output('This user account is currently locked!', 'Account Locked', 'Error');
  }
  else
  {
   /* User can be unlocked and form be resubmitted */
   $this->users_model->unlock_user($user_data->user_id);
   $this->submit($post_username, $post_password);
   return FALSE;
  }

  /* User is unlocked from logging in */

  if ($user_data->user_status_id != 2)
  {
   /* User has a status that is not allowed to proceed */
   $this->user_status_message($user_data->user_status_id);
  }

  /* User is registered and validated */

  $regenerated_post_password = $this->genfunc->reGenPassHash($post_password, $user_data->password_hash);

  $failed_logins = $this->session->userdata('failed_logins');

  if ($regenerated_post_password !== $user_data->password)
  {
   /* Password from login from does not match user stored password */

   if ($failed_logins == 0)
   {
    /* First time user has not entered username and password successfully */
    $this->session->set_userdata('failed_logins', 1);
    $this->users_model->increase_login_attempt($this->input->ip_address(), $post_username, gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
    $this->output('Incorrect username and password credentials!', 'Incorrect Login Credentials', 'Error');
   }

   /* User has atleast one failed login attempt for the current session */

   if ($failed_logins !== 4)
   {
    /* User has a few more chances to get password right */
    $failed_logins++;
    $this->session->set_userdata('failed_logins', $failed_logins);
    $this->users_model->increase_login_attempt($this->input->ip_address(), $post_username, gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
    $this->output('Incorrect username and password credentials!', 'Incorrect Login Credentials', 'Error');
   }

   $this->users_model->lock_out_user($user_data->user_id, gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+(60*15)));
   //$this->functions_model->send_email('maximum_failed_login_attempts_exceeded', $user_data->email_address, $user_data)
   $this->output('Your account is currently locked, we apologize for the inconvienence. You must wait 15 minutes before you can log in again! An email was sent to the owner of this account! Forgotten your username or password? <a href="forgotusername">Forgot Username</a> or <a href="forgotpassword">Forgot Password</a>', 'Account Locked', 'Error');

  }

  /* Password from login form matches user stored password and user may login */

  $this->output('Successful login! Sending you to the dashboard!', 'Login Sucessful', 'Success');
 }
```

Any Idea ???

Comment: Does this happen only with `AJAX`? Did you try regular "form - post" + profiling data, and echoing some values on lines that you "suspect" are doing this? Check all parameters (that are beeing send to functions if they are same after "recieving" by desired function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just going through your code i can see that within your submit function you call again the submit function, which leads to an endless recursive behaviour.

so there must be a problem in your **users_model** model on **unlock_user()** function.

```
if ($this->is_user_locked($user_data->lock_date))
  {
   /* User is locked from logging in from too many failed attempts */
   $this->output('This user account is currently locked!', 'Account Locked', 'Error');
  }
  else
  {
   /* User can be unlocked and form be resubmitted */
   $this->users_model->unlock_user($user_data->user_id);
   $this->submit($post_username, $post_password); // <- here
   return FALSE;
  }
```